# A bit complicated alignment situation

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I have something like this:

[image]

Of course with a,b,c, etc. being some expressions.

I would like to align the equal signs in "a = b = c" with the equal signs in "g = h = i" and the equal signs in "d = e = f" with the equal signs in "j = k = l".

Please note that I would like to have "d = e = f" on the same line as "a = b = c", and "j = k = l" on the same line as "g = h = i", just as displayed in the snippet I attached. That is actually what is causing me trouble, because otherwise I know how to do this using the align environment.

I am not sure how to go about this. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried the `align` environment from `amsmath`? I believe it does exactly what you want.

Comment: The `alignat` environment could also be useful.

Comment: `alignat`, `array`, ... however, if math terms have different length, result will not be nice :-(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In general you'll receive better answers if you show us some code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}[t]{rclcl@{\qquad}rclcl}
a & = & bbbbbbb & = & c,    &  a & = & b & = & c, \\
g & = & h & = & iiiiiiii,   & gg & = & h & = & iiiiiiii 
\end{array}
\]

\begin{alignat*}{9}
a & = & b & = c,  &\qquad&    a & = & b & = c\\
g & = & h & = i,  &      &    g & = & h & = i  
\end{alignat*}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

As yo can see, result is not very pleasant, if the math terms have different length. In solution with `array` you can play with different columns types, for example to use only `c` type. In this case then result will be equal as at  solution with  `alignat`.

Comment: Hi Zarko. Thank you! But I also want "d = e = f" on the same line as "a = b = c" and later "j = k = l" on the same line as "g = h = i", and I want to separate them by commas. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Math spacing wrong in `alignat`.  Just sayin'